# .NetFramework ( C# ) Visual Presentation Foundation and Deployment

Tags: c#

I am having a problem deploying an application using a file system, I am reading and writing a file in my application if I run my file in my visual studio it runs but when published it freezes.
How can I deploy a WPF C#.NET application with file system pls help?

Comment: Where is the application and the file you are trying to access? In the program files directory?

Comment: yes yes yes pls show me how but I don't know how to do that pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Could be freezing because it can't find the file you're trying to import since the directory will change after deployment. If you're not using an OpenFileDialog control to select your file then I'd suggest doing that.

Comment: I am not trying to export it and I don't want to export It because I want it to work backend for processing. Can you show me the way to publish an application that reads and writes files backend without a user knowing or you having to use dialogues?